# If $f$ has more than one root in $K$, then $f$ splits and $K/k$ is Galois?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $f \in k[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial of prime degree $p$ such that $K \cong k[x]/f(x)$ is a separable extension. How do I see that if $f$ has more than
one root in $K$, then $f$ splits and $K/k$ is Galois?

Answer (score 9):

Let $G=\mathrm{Aut}(K/k)$. Since $f$ has more than one root in $K$, it follows that $|G|>1$.

Suppose that $|G|<p$, and choose some $1\neq\sigma\in G$ of order $q$. Let $F$ be the subfield of $K$ fixed by $\sigma$. Then by Artin's theorem, it follows that $K/F$ is a Galois extension, with $[K:F]=|\sigma|=q$.

Therefore
$$p=[K:k]=[K:F][F:k]=q[F:k] $$
which is a contradiction because $q<p$ and $p$ is prime.

Hence $|G|=p$, so $K$ is a Galois extension of $k$ and $f$ splits in $K$.

Comment: Much simpler than my argument!

Answer (score 5):

Let $L\supseteq K$ be a splitting field of $f$ over $k$, and let $G=\operatorname{Gal}(L/k)$ be the Galois group. As $f$ is separable, it has $p$ distinct roots in $L$. We view $G$ as a group of permutations of the roots, so also as a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_p$. Denote by $H=\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)\le G$ the subgroup associated to the intermediate field $K$.

The order of $G$ is divisible by $[K:k]=p$ so by Cauchy's theorem there exists an element $\sigma\in G$ of order $p$. When viewed as an element of $S_p$ $\sigma$ has to be a $p$-cycle.

Let $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ be two roots of $f(x)$ in $K$. By replacing $\sigma$ with its suitable power we can without loss of generality assume that $\sigma(\alpha_1)=\alpha_2$. Number the zeros in such a way that $\sigma(\alpha_i)=\alpha_{i+1}$, for all $i=1,2,\ldots,p-1$, $\sigma(\alpha_p)=\alpha_1$.

The claim is to prove that all the zeros $\alpha_i\in K$. Assume contrariwise that this is not the case. Then we can find three zeros $\alpha_i,\alpha_{i+1},\alpha_{i+2}$ such that $\alpha_i,\alpha_{i+1}\in K$ but $\alpha_{i+2}\notin K$.
This implies that there exists an element $\tau\in H$ such that $\tau(\alpha_{i+2})\neq\alpha_{i+2}$. Consider the automorphism $\delta=\sigma^{-1}\tau\sigma$. As $\tau$ fixes all the elements of $K$
$$
\delta(\alpha_i)=\sigma^{-1}(\tau(\alpha_{i+1}))=\sigma^{-1}(\alpha_{i+1})=\alpha_i.
$$
Therefore $\delta$ fixes the elements of $k(\alpha_i)\subseteq K$. As $[K:k]=p$ is a prime, we can conclude that there are no intermediate fields between $k$ and $K$. Hence $k(\alpha_i)=K$, and $\delta\in H$. 
But,
$$
\delta(\alpha_{i+1})=\sigma^{-1}(\tau(\alpha_{i+2}))\neq\sigma^{-1}(\alpha_{i+2})=\alpha_{i+1}.
$$
So $\delta$ does not fix the element $\alpha_{i+1}$ contradicting the above, and proving the claim.

Comment: The case $p=2$ is uninteresting, so I could assume $p\ge3$.

Comment: Do you have a typo (missing 'Gal' or 'Aut') in your definition of $H$? - i.e., the sentence starting with "Denote by $H = L/K$"  - nice argument, btw

Comment: Thanks @peterag! There was, indeed, a typo.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Wouldn't it be easier to do this:  As $K=k[\alpha_1]$, then $\sigma\upharpoonright K:K\rightarrow K$. As $\sigma$ is a $p$-cycle, then for any $1\leq i\leq p$ there is some $j$ such that $\sigma^j(\alpha_1)=\alpha_i$, so that $\alpha_i\in K$.

Comment: Absolutely, @CamiloArosemena ! That was in some vague sense my plan initially, but for some reason I felt it didn't work. But, why wouldn't it? You should post that as an answer!

Comment: With regards to @CamiloArosemena-Serrato comment, how do we know that $\sigma$ restricted to $K$ has image in $K$? Since we don't know whether $K$ is normal yet.

Comment: @eatfood A good point. Because $K=k(\alpha_1)=k(\alpha_2)$ there exists an automorphism $\tau$ of $K$ such that $\tau(\alpha_1)=\alpha_2$. Because also $\sigma(\alpha_1)=\alpha_2$, it follows that $\sigma$ and $\tau$ agree on $K$. IIRC that's the way I thought it would go :-)