# Show: If some $x_i \neq x_1$ occurs as $\sigma(x_1)$ for a $\sigma \in$ Gal$ (E:F)$ then each $x_i\neq x_1$ occurs as $\sigma(x_1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, galois-theory, quintics

I'm currently studying Galois Theory (or am trying to do so), and since almost two weeks I try over and over again to solve a particular question from a textbook (J. Stillwell, Elements of Algebra, p. 132).

Task: Consider the extension $E=F(x_1)$ of $ F=\mathbb{Q}(a_0,...,a_4)$. $x_1$ is a root of the quintic $x^5+a_4 x^4 + ... + a_0 =0$ (the other four roots being depicted as $x_2$ to $x_5$). Show

(i) $\sigma \in$ Gal$(E:F)$ is determined by the value $\sigma(x_1)$.

(ii) $\sigma(x_1)$ is a root of $x^5+a_4 x^4 + ... + a_0 =0$, hence $|$Gal$(E:F)| <= 5$.

(iii) If some $x_i \neq x_1$ occurs as $\sigma(x_1)$ for a $\sigma \in $ Gal$ (E:F)$ then each $x_i\neq x_1$ occurs as $\sigma(x_1)$

```
It turned out that irreducibility of the quintic over F, although not stated explicitly,
is absolutely necessary for claim (iii) to be true, see comments below.
```

I had little trouble to show (i) and (ii), but (iii) is giving me a headache permanently. Here is what I tried:

====================================================================

(Trial A)

Suppose $\sigma(x_1) = x_2$, and $\sigma \in $ Gal$(E:F)$. Then:

$\Rightarrow \sigma(f) = f $ for all $ f\in F$ by definition of Galois Groups, and $x_i \in E$ since $\sigma$ is an automorphism on E.

$\Rightarrow $ There must be a rational function $q$ of $x_2$ with $x_1 = q(x_2)$, because $x_1$ must be the result for one $\sigma(q(x_1)) = q(\sigma(x_1)) = q(x_2)$

$\Rightarrow x_2 = \sigma(x_1)=\sigma(q(x_2)) = q(x_1)$ and thus: $\sigma^2(x_1)=\sigma(x_2)=q(\sigma(x_1))=q(x_2)=x_1$. Thus $\sigma$ is its own inverse.

```
This was not correct, see comment below. 
Thus the next conclusion is wrong, also.
```

$\Rightarrow $ Now $\{1,\sigma\}$ is closed under multiplication, it is easy to see that it is a group. Although I don't know whether it actually *is* the Galois-Group of E over F, it could be. At least I don't see a reason from here why it shouldn't be fine, or why I would have to include more $x_i$ necessarily.

EDIT#2: From this point I tried to construct a counterexample to the statement to be shown, in order to see which are the obstacles. If I have two roots $x_1$ and $x_2$ with a corresponding automorphism, I can choose the other three roots as definitely lying outside of $\mathbb{Q}(a_0,...,a_4,x_1)$. Then with
$ (x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)(x-x_5)$ I have a polynomial with three roots outside of $E$, contradicting the statement to be shown. Reason: if $x_i \notin  E$ there cannot be an automorphism $\sigma \in $ Gal$ (E:F)$ with $\sigma(e) = x_i$ for some $e \in E$. However, the field $F=\mathbb{Q}(a_0, ...a_4)$ is determined by the choice of $x_3, x_4$ and $x_5$, via the $a_i$. Thus it is still possible that I cannot find roots outside $F$ just by this feedback behavior. This would again point towards some argument of the kind: Because two roots are fixed, the others will be in $\mathbb{Q}(a_0, ...a_4)$ since they can be calculated by $x_1$, $x_2$ and the $a_i$. What to do from here...?

====================================================================

(Trial B)

The next try was to go over the symmetric elementary polynomials $a_1,...,a_4$. If I assumed two roots $x_1$ and $x_2$ to lie in $E$, is it possible to calculate the other roots from the $a_i$? Well, it seems to be. That means that with $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $E$ all the others would lie in $E$, too, and it remains to show that the corresponding automorphisms exist. But I only could hack it with mathematica, and the result is rather complicated. I doubt that this was the authors intention. Additionally, I cannot see why then it shouldn't be possible to calculate four roots out of $x_1$, with the five elementary polynomials.

EDIT#1: I discovered a serious misinterpretation in my Trial B. I can compute expressions $f(a_0, ...,a_4)$ for each $x_3, x_4$ and $x_5$, respectively. But they contain $\sqrt{}$ and $\sqrt[3]{}$ operations, and thus are not in $E = \mathbb{Q}(a_0,...,a_4,x_1)$. If I'm right, this rules out Trial B as an appropriate way to show what is asked. It must have something to do with the automorphisms in general, some symmetry-argument maybe, but I don't know.

```
As I see it according to the solution of Jyrki, the a_i do indeed
determine which x_i are in E and what the automorphisms are. 
But this is shown via the general properties of E, not by direct calculation.
```

Please, can someone help me?

Comment: If $\omega\in Gal(E:F)$ then $\omega$ can only be the identity since it must fix $F$ and send all other elements in $E$ to other elements of $E$. But that will always simplify to $\omega(x_1) =x_1$

Comment: @AndrewShedlock : I don't think this is generally true. Think about a quintic with $x_1=\sqrt{2}$ and $x_2=-\sqrt{2}$, the other three roots left unspecified for the moment. Then $x_2 \in E = \mathbb{Q}(a_0,...,a_4,\sqrt{2})$, and there is an automorphism $\sigma(\sqrt{2})=-\sqrt{2}$ on $E$ that leaves all the $a_i$ and all $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ unchanged. Hence $\sigma \in $ Gal$(E:F)$ and $\sigma \neq Identity$.

Comment: Some key assumptions must be missing. Presumably $x_1$ is a zero of the quintic $x^5+a_4x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$. And presumably also it is given that this quintic is irreducible over $F$. For otherwise the claim (ii) may be false. For example, without those assumptions it is possible that $E=F$ when the Galois group is trivial.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:
$x_1$ is considered a Zero of the quintic, as you mentioned. The same for $x_2$ to $x_5$.

The quintic is not irreducible by assumption. Thanks to your comment I realized a typo: it's $|$Gal$(E:F)|<=5$, not $|$Gal$(E:F)|>=5$. I corrected that.

Comment: Please add the missing pieces also to the question body. But, as you observed yourself, it is possible that the quintic is of the form $(x^2-2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)(x-x_5)$ with $x_3,x_4,x_5\in F$, $\sqrt2\notin F$. In that case claim (iii) is FALSE. You absolutely need irreducibility of the quintic over $F$ for (iii) to be true.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, done. Irreducibility of the quintic is nowhere explicitly stated. That's why I haven't incorporated that into the question body, yet. Lets assume it was stated: I agree with you that this is necessary for Claim (iii) not to be obviously false. But does it make claim (iii) true, *if* we assume irreducibility?

Comment: what are $a_0, \ldots a_4$ ?

Comment: @mercio. They are the coefficients of the general quinitc polynomial and the elementary symmetric polynomials in $x_1,...,x_5$.

Comment: An error in your Trial (A): You only get
$$x_2=\sigma(x_1)=\sigma(q(x_2))=q(\sigma(x_2)).$$ You have not said anything about $\sigma(x_2)$ (and it will turn out that $\sigma(x_2)$ has to be one of $x_3,x_4,x_5$).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen My thinking was, that since an automorphism is surjective each element in $E$, hence also $x_1$ must be the result of some $\sigma(q) = x_1$ with $q \in E$. And I thougth about $E = F(x_1)$ as the rational $q(x_1)$ functions of $x_1$ with coefficients from $\mathbb{Q}$ and $a_0,...a_4$. Hence the reasoning $\Rightarrow x_1 = \sigma(q(x_1))=q(\sigma(x_1))=q(x_2)$.

Comment: Ahh...I see the point. I cannot believe it...

Comment: are $a_0, \ldots, a_4$ unspecified complex numbers ? or unspecified algebraic numbers ? or indeterminates ?

Comment: They are complex numbers in general. They are defined by the equation $$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)(x-x_5)=x^5+a_4 x^4 + .... a_0.$$ According to this definition they are the symmetric elementary polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recapping the setting: $F=\Bbb{Q}(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ so the polynomial
$$
p(x)=x^5+a_4x^4+a3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0\in F[x].$$
We further denote the zeros of $p(x)$ (in some extension of $F$) by $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_5$, and also denote $E=F(x_1)$.

**Assumption.** There exists a non-trivial $F$-automorphism $\sigma$ of $E$.

**Extra assumption.** The polynomial $p(x)$ is irreducible in $F[x]$.

**Claim.** Given the extra assumption all the zeros $x_i, i>1,$ are in the field $E$. Furthermore, $\sigma$ is necessarily of order five and it permutes the five roots in a 5-cycle. In particular, given $x_i, i\neq1$, there exists an exponent $\ell$ (depending on $i$) such that $\sigma^\ell(x_1)=x_i$.

**Proof.** The extra assumption implies that $[E:F]=\deg p(x)=5$. I will heavily use the fact that five is a prime. Most notably, it follows that there are no intermediate fields $L$ such that $F\subset L\subset E$. This is immediate from the multiplicativity of the extension degree in a tower of field extension.

Consider the set $M$ of fixed points of $\sigma$
$$
M=\{z\in E\mid \sigma(z)=z\}.
$$
It is known that $M$ is field (do this as an exercise if you haven't seen it yet - all you need is that $\sigma$ is an automorphism of fields). Because $\sigma$ is not the identity mapping, $M$ is a proper subfield of $E$. OTOH $\sigma$ is an $F$-automorphism of $E$, so $F\subseteq M$. Lack of intermediate fields implies that $M=F$.

Another standard fact is that if $z\in E$ is a zero of $p(x)$ then so is $\sigma(z)$. Consequently all the numbers $x_1,\sigma(x_1),\sigma^2(x_1),\ldots$ are elements of $E$, and they are all zeros of $p(x)$. Because $p(x)$ has at most five zeros in $E$ there exists an exponent $m, 1<m\le5,$ such that $\sigma^m(x_1)=x_1$. (Proof: there must be repetitions among those iterates, say $\sigma^i(x_1)=\sigma^j(x_1)$ for some $i<j$, because $\sigma$ is a bijection we can cancel some, and reduce to the case $i=0$.)

Consider the polynomial
$$
m(x)=\prod_{i=0}^{m-1}(x-\sigma^i(x_1))\in E[x].
$$
Because the sets $\{\sigma^i(x_1)\mid 0\le i<m\}$ and
$\{\sigma^i(x_1)\mid 0<i\le m\}$ are equal. It follows that if we apply $\sigma$ to all the coefficients of $m(x)$ we must get $m(x)$ back. In other words $m(x)\in M[x]=F[x]$. On the other hand, $m(x)$ is a factor of $p(x)$ (all zeros of $m(x)$ are simple and also zeros of $p(x)$). The extra assumption about the irreducibility of $p(x)$ then implies that $m(x)=p(x)$.
In particular $m=5$. Consequently $p(x)$ has five zeros in $E$. The other claims follow from this.

**What happens if we drop the extra assumption?**

Assume instead that $p(x)=r(x)s(x)$ non-trivially. Without loss of generality
$r(x_1)=0$, and we can assume that $r(x)$ is irreducible over $F$ (i.e. the minimal polynomial of $x_1$ over $F$). If we also assume claim (iii) then all the zeros of $s(x)$ must appear as automorphic images of $x_1$. But those images are also zeros of $r(x)$. In other words, the zeros of $s(x)$ must all be zeros of $r(x)$. It can be shown (we may need a few more pieces of theory here) that all the zeros of $p(x)$ must have the same multiplicity, implying that $\deg r(x)\mid \deg p(x)$. Again, as five is a prime, this leaves us with the possibilities of $r(x)=p(x)$ and the possibility $\deg r(x)=1$. In the latter case $F(x_1)=F$ and we arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: Halfway through this I noticed that I'm reproducing pieces of Galois theory that you may have not seen yet. I think there is a sleeker argument. That's why I left the last part a bit sketchy. Thinking...

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1853221/11619) is what this exercise looks like with a bit more theory in place!

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. I worked through it yesterday.

"Another standard fact is that if z∈E  is a zero of p(x)  then so is σ(z)" --> I think this is a consequence of the automorphism properties of $\Sigma$ and the fact that if $0 = x_1^5 + a_4*x_1^4 + ... + a_0$ then also $\sigma(0) = 0 = (\sigma(x_1))^5 + ... a_0$. Correct?

Now, I still don't get the next argument. If I take the automorphism $\sigma(x_1)=  x_2$ as in my question body, then I have exponent $m=2$, and the polynomial $m = (x-x_1)^3(x-x_2)^2$, not a factor of $p$ in general. Where is my flaw?

Comment: Revising my comment I see my flaw: $ m = (x-x_1)(x-x_2)$ according to your definition. Then it certainly is a factor of $p$. Consequence: there is no $\sigma$ with $\sigma^m(x_1)=x_1$ and $ m=2$, as I constructed in my body text...I will try to figure out where my false assumption Comes from

Comment: Ok, I see now that I got totally biased by the example of the automorphism $\sigma(\sqrt{2}) = -\sqrt{2}$ on $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. What I did not realize was

1. That $\sigma$ does not necessarily extend to $\mathbb{Q}(a_0,...a_4,\Sqrt{2}$, since $F = \mathbb{Q}(a_0,...,a_4,x_1)$ has degree five and not two.

2. That the quinitc is not irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(a_0,...a_4,\Sqrt{2}$ if $\Sqtr{2}$ and $-\Sqrt{2}$ are both roots of the polynomial and hence this example is not a valid one.

Comment: The amount of theory is good, does not contain anything that had not been covered in the textbook at the point where this task is given. Thank you for your help. I learnt a good deal of the topic by the struggle with this task and your comments/answers.

Comment: May I ask for your feedback on an additional point? The last two parts of the exercise (omitted from the question posted above) ask us to show that $Aut(F(x_1)/F)$ is trivial. Unless I am mistaken, since it has been shown that if there exists a non-identity element of $Aut(F(x_1)/F)$, then the roots $x_1,...,x_5$ of the irreducible polynomial $x^5 + a_4x^4 + ... + a_1x + a_0$ all belong to $F(x_1)$, it must be the case that $S_5 \subseteq Aut(F(x_1)/F)$, which yields the contradiction $5! = |S_5| \leq |Aut(F(x_1)/F)| \leq 5$. Therefore, $Aut(F(x_1)/F)$ must be trivial.