# How can I show this field is a normal extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Say $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, where $\alpha(=\alpha_1)$ is an algebraic element over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $[K : \mathbb{Q}] = p$ (here  $p$ is an odd prime number).

$\alpha_1,\alpha_2, ...,\alpha_p $ are the algebraic conjugate elements of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Moreover $\alpha_2 \in K $.

Show that $K$ is a normal extension (or Galois extension) field of $\mathbb{Q}$.

---

The solution of this is below.

**Solution**. Let $p(x) = \mathrm{irr}(\alpha, \mathbb{Q})$ and $E= \mathrm{SF}(p(x)/\mathbb{Q})$.

$\mathbb{Q} \subset K \subset E$ for the Galois extension $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ $\Rightarrow$ $p = [K:\mathbb{Q}] \vert [E : \mathbb{Q}] = \vert G(E/Q )\vert$.

By Cauchy $\exists$ $\sigma \in G(E/Q)$ s.t. $\vert \sigma \vert =p$ and $\sigma^k(\alpha_i) = \alpha_j\ \forall i,j$.

Take $\sigma^m(\alpha) =\alpha_2(\in K) $ for some $m \in \{1,2,...,p-1\}$

So $\sigma^m\vert_K : K \to K$.

Hence $\color{blue}{\forall i=1,2,3,...,p-1, (\sigma^m\vert_K)^i(\alpha) \in K}$ $\color{blue}{\Rightarrow}$
$\color{blue}{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_p \in K}$.

**Question**. I can't understand why the blue colored parts hold. Is the idea $(\sigma^m\vert_K)^i(\alpha) = \alpha_i \in K$? If so, how can we say $(\sigma^m\vert_K)^i(\alpha)\in K$? In my thought $K$ only guarantees including $\alpha_1$ and  $\alpha_2$ not the others.

P.S. Other solutions are also welcome.

Comment: The problem is discussed [in this older thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1853221/11619). My answer is a bit kludgy. The accepted answer and Camilo Arosemena's comment under mine point at something slicker (IIRC).

Comment: Anyway, the problem you seem to ask about is resolved as follows. $\sigma^m(\alpha_1)=\alpha_2$. Therefore $\sigma^m$ maps $K=\Bbb{Q}(\alpha_1)$ to $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha_2)$. In other words $\sigma^m(K)=K$. In particular $\sigma^m(\alpha_2)\in K$. But $\sigma^m$ has order $p$ as a permutation of the roots. So you A) get all the other zeros  by applying $\sigma^m$ sufficiently many times, B) never leave $K$ while doing that because $\sigma^m(K)=K$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put differently, let $G$ be the Galois group of a normal closure of $K$ over ${\bf Q}$ and let $H$ be the subgroup of automorphisms that fix $K$. We want to show that $H$ is normal in $G$.

Then $G$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_p$. Let $H$ be the stabilizer of $\alpha_1$. By transitivity $\alpha_2=\sigma(\alpha_1)$ for some $\sigma\in G$. The fact that $H$ fixes $\alpha_2$ means that we have $H\subset\sigma H\sigma^{-1}$ and hence $H=\sigma H\sigma^{-1}$. Since $\sigma\not\in H$ and $[G:H]$ is prime, $G$ is generated by $H$ and $\sigma$. Therefore $H$ is normal in $G$.